# I am getting this error while making a small app using react can someone help me this

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react I am making a small app using reactjs when I added this file and run the code it is giving this error no syntactical error are shown.
this is the code which I have written.

```
import React from { react }
import Card from "./Card"

const CardList = ({ robots }) => {
  //const cardComponent=robots.map((user,i)=>{
  return (
    // key prop should have something that should not be changed
    <div>
      {
        robots.map((user, i) => {
          <Card
            key={i}
            id={robots[i].id}
            name={robots[i].name}
            email={robots[i].email} />
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardList
```

the app should run smooth.[thsi is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9bRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is. Your import is not right. If there is another please add code for more info

```
import React from 'react';//not what you import
import Card from "./Card";

const CardList = ({ robots }) => { //const cardComponent=robots.map((user,i)=>{ return ( // key prop should have something that should not be changed { robots.map((user, i) => { }) } ) }
```

Comment: Thanks shubham i will see it, i have also tried changing folder structure